# Creating path of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I should have an array, and I want to `MERGE` all the element in the array into a path of nodes so that when given the relationship name, the nodes will be created if they do not already exist and then joined underneath each other in which the last element in the array will be the leaf node. How do I write this in CYPHER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to transform an array of elements into a sequential path of nodes use the following query:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5] as start
UNWIND start as a
MERGE (l:Label{id:a})
WITH collect(l) as array
    FOREACH(i in RANGE(0, length(array)-2) |
       FOREACH(element1 in [array[i]] |
           FOREACH(element2 in [array[i+1]] |
    MERGE (element1)-[:NEXT]->(element2))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I want. Even though the description of the question seems vague, just didn't know how else to put it. Each element in the array starting from the beginning should fall under themselves till the end of the list forming a straight path.

Answer (score 1):

Tomaž's answer is correct, and the way to do this with Cypher alone.

As a supplement to this, if you have [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) installed, you can use a procedure to perform this linking for you.

Using Tomaž's query with slight modification:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5] as start
UNWIND start as a
MERGE (l:Label{id:a})
WITH collect(l) as array
CALL apoc.nodes.link(array, 'NEXT')
RETURN true // since we can't end the query on a procedure call
```